# Problem with the command filter() in R? Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a database by some variables, and I don't know why when I run the filter () command I get an error and I have the database all NA's.

[image]

The message is

Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Comment: Make sure you're using `dplyr::filter` and not `stats::filter`. (Type `filter` on the console, and if you get anything other than `<environment: namespace:dplyr>` as the last line of output, it means you aren't using `dplyr::filter`.) You may need to call `library(dplyr)` (though I would have expected `\`%>%\` not found` or similar), or ... something else.

Comment: No one can run this except you.  Please provide a reproducible example as per the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag.

Comment: Yes, that was it , thanks very much